# In Red (R2) how to call a function whose name passed by argument?

Tags: rebol, red, rebol2

I have an arbitrary function with multiple arguments, and I want to call it from command-line like this:
`program myfun 7 24 15`

I tried to do it this way:

```
myfun Func: [A B C][...]
ARGS: Probe System/Options/Args
Print Do [ARGS/1 Remove ARGS]
```

My way of thinking is that I retrieve command name with ARGS/1, then remove it from argument list, enclose in a block with the rest of arguments and evaluate with Do. However, it just returns arguments without the function name: `7 24 15`. I also tried to copy both values to different variables, but no luck, and I cannot understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that the last line does not do what you think it should:

```
Do [ARGS/1 Remove ARGS]
```

will return:

```
["7" "24" "15"]
```

instead of calling `myfun` function with those arguments. That happens because `do [args/1]` is not equivalent to `do args/1`:

```
>> args: ["myfun" "7" "24" "15"]
== ["myfun" "7" "24" "15"]
>> Do [ARGS/1]
== "myfun"
>> Do ARGS/1
*** Script Error: myfun has no value
*** Where: Do
*** Near : myfun
*** Stack:
```

As you can see, in the first case, `do` is evaluating a block and returning the last value, so `Args/1` is evaluated to `"myfun"` and returned by `do`. In the second case, `Args/1` is evaluated to `"myfun"`, then `"myfun"` is passed as argument to `do`, resulting in `do` loading that value and evaluating it (resulting in an error in my case, as I did not define that word).

> However, it just returns arguments without the function name: 7 24 15

Using `print` implies an extra level of evaluation (as `print` reduces its block of arguments), so you can easily get fooled by the reduced output. If you use `probe` instead (recommended for debugging), you would get `["7" "24" "15"]`.

Now to achieve what you want, you can either do it yourself, step by step or use an existing library.

#### Directly coding the solution

Here is an example code:

```
Red [File: %program.red]

to-int: :to-integer
myfun:  func [a b c][(to-int a) + (to-int b) + (to-int c)]

args: system/options/args
print apply to-word args/1 next args
```

This approach relies on `apply` which will call a function (passed as word or function value) with a list of arguments (passed as a block of values). So:

1. `to-word args/1` fetches and converts the function's name to the right type.
2. `next args` creates the list of arguments by skipping the function's name at first position in the block (no needs to remove it, just skipping is simpler).
3. The arguments are provided as string values by Red, so you have to convert them to the right type before use.

#### Using a library

The [CLI library](https://codeberg.org/hiiamboris/red-cli) is doing what you need (and a lot more). Feel free to join us in our [Chat room](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/!wUTlqkqOhNGtfQzIsO:matrix.org) if you're not there already and ask @hiiamboris if you need any info about his CLI library.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works! While waiting, I have also found two other ways to do it: by making map! with name handlers and then calling them with `print get select handlers args`, and doing `print load form args`. However, the second one doesn't work when one of arguments is an unquoted string.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see newcomers here.
In short:

1. The assignment is ":". You put it on the wrong token, should be `myfun: func [][A B C`
2. `system/options/args` are a list of strings.  Better to have whole argument itself as one string. So use `system/options/args`
3. No neet to rearrange, just call `print do system/options/args`

If "do" is called with a string as argument, the string is tokenized and bound to the global environment before executed.

So try this in a file called test.r

```
REBOL [] 
args: system/options/args
myfunc: func [ ][ print "from the function" ]
do probe myfunc
```

And call it with `rebol test.r myfunc 1 2 3`